# CanExecute не срабатывает при изменении параметра

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-commands

Тестирую команды wpf. Имеется следующая модель представления с командой `AddClient`:

```
public class WindowMainVM :VM
{
    public WindowMainVM(List<Participant> participants)
    {
        Clients = new ObservableCollection<Participant>(participants);
        AddClient = new CmdAddClient(selectedClient);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Participant> Clients { get; set; }
    private Participant selectedClient;
    public Participant SelectedClient
    {
        get { return selectedClient; }
        set { selectedClient = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedClient"); }
    }

//...
    public CmdAddClient AddClient { get; private set; } 
}
```

И имеется класс - реализация интерфейса ICommand `CmdAddClient` в конструктор которой передается свойство модели `selectedClient`. Суть в том, что `CanExecute` должен возвращать `true` если свойство модели представления `selectedClient` не равно `null`.

```
public class CmdAddClient : ICommand
{
    public CmdAddClient (object obj)
    {
        clientObject = obj;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
    private object clientObject { get; set; }
    
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (clientObject != null)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что хотя свойству модели представления успешно присваивается значение, приватное свойство `clientObj` в классе команды остается равным null и соответственно `CanExecute` никогда не возвращает `true`.

Comment: Судя по описанию, вы опрашиваете не тот экземпляр класса, в который записали объект. Вообще команды немного по-другому используют, попробуйте это решение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1281193/373567. `CanExecute` срабатывает на каждое событие ввода, то есть нажатие клавиши, тык мышкой в интерфейс и т.д. Используйте делегаты, как в примере по ссылке, и не придется копировать или изменять класс реализации команды.

Comment: @aepot Про передачу делегата мне известно. Просто нет понимания почему конкретно здесь, когда полю `selectedClient` в модели присваивается значение, то изменения не отражаются в поле `clientObjесt` класса команды. Объект ведь передается по ссылке, разве нет?

Comment: Передается, но вы не показали, как это тестируете, и как именно вы узнали, что там null. Не мудрите, сначала попробуйте то, что я показал.