# Реализация интерфейса ICommand. В каком формате передавать данные в команду?

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

Хочу написать консольный калькулятор. По заданию, нужно использовать паттерн команда.

1. создаю интерфейс ICommand:

   ```
    public interface ICommand
    {
        void Execute();
    }
   ```
2. Приступаю к реализации команд.
   Вопрос, как правильно передать данные в команду?
   Я решил использовать string, но допустимо ли передавать числа через string. Есть ли какие-нибудь общепринятые способы/стандарты и т.п.?

   ```
    private object[] Summand;

    public void Execute()
    {
        Sum();
    }
    public SumCommand(string[] summands)
    {
        Summand = new object[summands.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < summands.Length; i++)
           Summand[i] = new DataTable().Compute(summands[i],null);
            //Summand[i] =summands[i]; //вот так можно упростить конструкцию, может так и сделать?
    }
    public string Sum()
    {
        double result=0;
        for(int i=0;i<Summand.Length;i++)
        {
            result += Convert.ToDouble(Summand[i]) ;
        }
        return  result.ToString();
    }
   ```

Comment: [Вот так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1281193/373567) реализация команды выглядеть должна. Кстати, [не я это придумал](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic). Кстати интерфейс [ICommand](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand?view=net-5.0) уже есть в дотнете (WPF). Параметр передается аргументом `void Execute(object parameter);`

Comment: @aepot, это вопрос больше отностися к шаблонам проектирования в целом, чем к WPF. System.Windows.Input.Command - это одна из реализаций. В ряде случаев неудобная. В общем виде паттерн команда описан примерно так, как у ТС вот здесь: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/command

Comment: @Uranus не знаю, мне удобно. По поводу шаблона, его задача скрыть детали реализации команды от вызывающего класса. При этом вызывающий может знать только 2 вещи: имя команды и параметр, который требуется передать в Execute. А WPF - это боевой пример хорошего применения этого шаблона проектирования.

Answer (score 3):

В концепцию паттерна "Команда" не входит описание формата хранения параметров. Это детали реализации. Поэтому руководствуйтесь здравым смыслом и архитектурой приложения, для которого предназначен данный компонент:

1. Параметры должно быть удобно передавать извне.
2. Параметры должно быть удобно использовать внутри.

Например, в вашем примере, для сложения двух чисел необходимо конвертировать параметры из строки в число. Это неудобство ничем не оправдано, потому что параметры нигде не используются как строки в вашем коде. Было бы лучше если бы параметры были числами.

С другой стороны, может быть вызывающая сторона читает параметры из CSV файла или из консоли. В этом случае логично желание поместить код, преобразующий строки в числа - где-нибудь в одном месте. Можно добиться сразу обеих целей - если поместить код преобразования данных прямо в конструктор. Тогда вызывающая сторона будет передавать строки, но хранится они будут уже как числа.

С третьей стороны, строка ведь может содержать совсем и не числа. Может быть наоборот, вы захотите подсказать вызывающей стороне, что нужны именно числа, и ничто иное. Можно конечно бросать исключение, но если вместо этого изменить тип параметра на `double`, то вызывающая сторона еще на этапе написания кода будет предупреждена об ошибке. Но тогда, конечно, код преобразования данных будет размазан по приложению.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Вопрос возник в связи с тем, что заведомо неизвестно какого типа число будет передано. Поэтому я и хотел бы использовать нечто универсальное, но в итоге сталкиваюсь с проблемой конвертации, т.е. придется, как вариант, использовать что-то вроде switch для конвертации в нужное число. 
Либо использовать switch для идентефикации типа входящих данных

Comment: Возможно эта проблема стоит отдельного вопроса.